# How to convert nested array to multidimensional array(tensor) in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm dealing with a nested array, the array looks like:

```
feat=np.load('feat.npy',allow_pickle=True)
print(feat)
->array([array([[-1.0160675e+01, -1.3804866e+01,  9.1880971e-01, ...,
         1.5415058e+00,  1.1875046e-02, -5.8664594e+00],
       [-9.9697800e+00, -1.3823588e+01, -7.0778362e-02, ...,
         1.5948311e+00,  4.3481258e-01, -5.1646194e+00],
       [-9.9518738e+00, -1.2771760e+01, -1.2623003e-01, ...,
         3.4290311e+00,  2.7361808e+00, -6.0621500e+00],
       ...,
       [-9.9772453e+00, -1.8227636e+01,  5.4514462e-01, ...,
        -2.4311361e+01, -1.2033378e+01, -3.0492477e+00],
       [-9.8815651e+00, -1.3674727e+01,  5.1737971e+00, ...,
        -1.0951551e+01, -2.6184993e+00,  1.5815194e+00],
       [-1.0164914e+01, -1.2636200e+01,  4.4198503e+00, ...,
        -5.7269883e+00,  4.0758374e-01, -4.4462643e+00]], dtype=float32),
       array([[-12.862341 ,  -5.968506 , -20.532919 , ...,   3.1745207,
          6.5410886,  -8.223573 ],
       [-13.071164 ,  -6.0360484, -19.319475 , ...,   7.5193286,
          2.9258938, -13.224365 ],
       [-13.512331 ,  -4.9030676, -14.524248 , ...,  12.339673 ,
          4.6204743, -15.382669 ],
       ...,
       [-11.605266 ,  -7.1909204, -33.44656  , ..., -11.974911 ,
         12.825395 ,  10.635098 ],
       [-11.769397 ,  -9.340318 , -34.413307 , ..., -10.077869 ,
          8.821722 ,   7.704534 ],
       [-12.301968 , -10.67318  , -32.46104  , ...,  -6.829077 ,
         15.29837  ,  13.100596 ]], dtype=float32),
```

and I use numpy.ndarray.shape to get the shape of array is (105835,), and the first element of array is (99, 13), is there any way to convert the nested array to multidimensional array, eg.(105835,99,13)??

and I tried np.stack but it reports:

```
all input arrays must have the same shape
```

and if I use np.vstack then it becames 2D array:

```
temp=np.vstack(x)
temp.shape
->(9215279, 13)
```

Comment: try `np.stack`.  Report any errors.

Comment: `np.stack` will raise an error is the nested arrays differ in shape.  In fact that might be why that array has this nest structure originally.

Comment: @hpaulj I checked the data and find the nested arrays differ in shape, so it means I can't convert it into 3d array?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way you can post the part of code that is shaping the array?  I went ahead and tried the following that worked fine for me:

```
    import numpy
    #build random array
    array1 = [[[] for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]
    numpy.shape(array1)
```

It outputs (5,5,0) for me.

All below is my first edit to answer your comment:

I still think I need to see how you are trying to shape the array in your code.  This is what I did and I have no errors:

```
    a = array([array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]),array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])])
    b = shape(a)
    print(b)
```

It prints out (2, 2, 3).

Comment: It's a npy file containing MFCC features for wav. file, and feature data is stored as nested array.